# Oracle string operation to exclude specific characters based on delimiter

Tags: oracle

From the String `ES-123456-PSA Spain-101`, I need to extract only `ES-123456-101` Delimiter position is fixed.

Tried `REGEXP_SUBSTR('ES-123456-PSA Spain-101','[^-]+',2,3 )` which gives PSA Spain.

Is there a way to ignore those specific characters and returns rest of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `ES-123456-101` then use this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ES-123456-PSA Spain-101', '[^-]+-', '', 1, 3 )
FROM dual;
```

If you want `ES-12345-101` then could you explain the logic for `12345` not `123456`? Typo or omit the last character?

Comment: Just a typo, Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `subtr` and `instr`

```
with t as
(
  select 'ES-123456-PSA Spain-101' as text from dual
)

select substr(text,1,instr(text,'-',1,2)) -- ES-123456-
       ||substr(text,instr(text,'-',1,3)+1) -- 101
from t
```